# emacsclient: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, emacs

Having what feels like a really weird problem.

Running 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 as a virtual machine on a 64-bit Win7 host.

Open Emacs 23 and turn on server mode. In Bash, try to call emacsclient to edit some arbitrary script. The terminal just fires straight back, `emacsclient: command not found`.

Is there something that is likely to be missing? Some way of updating the  bash shell? It can find man pages for the command, so I know it's not something obvious like a misspelling.

Comment: Someone pointed me at the solution: I ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall emacs23-bin-common` and now emacsclient works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

OP provided an answer by himself:

> Someone pointed me at the solution: I ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall emacs23-bin-common` and now `emacsclient` works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Generally way to fix this kind of problems:

```
apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

Afterwards you can search for your missing command with:

```
 apt-file find bin/emacsclient
```

> emacs23-bin-common: /usr/bin/emacsclient.emacs23